# Como escrever esse algoritmo em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

A equação A^5+B^5+C^5+D^5+E^5=F^5 tal que 0<a<=b<=c<=d<=e<f<=75 tem exatamente uma solução inteira. escreva uma programa para encontra-la.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void){
int a=1,b=1,c=1,d=1,e=1,f=2,r,f5,ac,bc,cc,dc,ec,fc;

    for(a=1;a<=b;a++){
        for(b=1;b<=c;b++){
            for(c=1;c<=d;c++){
                for(d=1;d<=e;d++){
                    for(e=1;e<f;e++){
                        f=e+1;
                        for(;f<=75;f++){
                            r=pow(a,5)+pow(b,5)+pow(c,5)+pow(d,5)+pow(e,5);
                            f5=pow(f,5);
                            if(r==f5){
                                ac=a;
                                bc=b;
                                cc=c;
                                dc=d;
                                ec=e;
                                fc=f;
                                a=b=c=d=e=f=76;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
printf("A=%d,B=%d,C=%d,D=%d,E=%d,F=%d\n\n\n",ac,bc,cc,dc,ec,fc);

system("pause");
return (0);
}
```

Esse código entra em um loop infinito, minha cabeça travou, alguém sabe onde está o erro?

Comment: Note que o maior valor possível de armazenar em um `int` é 2.147.483.647. Como 75^5 = 2.373.046.875, ou utilize um unsigned int ou um long long.

Comment: Creio que o problema está nos loops.
Mesmo que ache o resultado, ele ainda continua a fazer o loops de f, e, d, c, b e a.
Fora também os problemas com o r, que precisa ser de mais espaço para armazenar o resultado da expreção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem mais de um problema na sua solução. Alguns deles:

A função `pow()` retorna um `double` e isso é problemático tanto quanto porque doubles não são exatos e pode ocorrer um erro na conversão para o `int` e tanto porque doubles possuem um range muito maior do que `int` e, portanto a conversão é perigosa.

No seu caso em determinado momento a função `pow()` retorna um valor superior ao range do `int` e as variáveis `r` e `f5` ficam com um valor indefinido. Quando eu testei o seu código, ambas assumiram o valor de -2.147.483.648

Isso leva ao segundo problema, o seguinte trecho  `a=b=c=d=e=f=76;` não faz com que as condições do loop sejam fechadas. Na realidade, os primeiros dois loops são fechados, mas quando chega neste `for(d=1;d <= e;d++)` tanto `d` como `e` são iguais a 76 e o loop prossegue infinitamente.

Enfim, eu corrigi os principais erros, mas mantive, em parte, a lógica que você adotou, confira-se:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//incluido o header stdint.h para usar o tipo int64_t 
//já que em alguns momentos os valores podem 
//ultrapassar o range do tipo int
#include <stdint.h>


//essa função substitui a pow() para evitar o uso de doubles
int64_t P(int x) {
    return x * x * x * x * x;
}

int main(){
    
    int AC, BC, CC, DC, EC, FC;
    
    //iniciar pelo F ao invés do A me pareceu mais legível
    for (int F = 1; F <= 75; F++) {     
        for (int E = 1; E <= F; E++) {
            for (int D = 1; D <= E; D++) {
                for (int C = 1; C <= D; C++) {
                    for (int B = 1; B <= C; B++) {
                        for (int A = 1; A <= B; A++) {  
                            int64_t F5 = P(F);
                            int64_t R = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) + P(E);
                            if (F5 - R == 0){
                                AC = A;
                                BC = B;
                                CC = C;
                                DC = D;
                                EC = E;
                                FC = F;
                                A = 81;// isso garante que todos os loops serão fechados
                                B = 80; // quando  a resposta correta for encontrada
                                C = 79;
                                D = 78;
                                E = 77; 
                                F = 76;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("A=%d,B=%d,C=%d,D=%d,E=%d,F=%d\n",
            AC, BC, CC, DC, EC, FC);
    
    return 0;    
}
```

Contudo, mesmo resolvendo o problema. Algo me incomoda nessa solução. Ela me parece bastante ineficiente porque verifica todas as combinações possíveis até encontrar a solução correta e é evidente que em determinadas circunstâncias muitas soluções podem ser descartadas. Por exemplo, se F = 70 e E = 10, é completamente desnecessário verificar o valor das outras variáveis já que ainda que elas tenham o mesmo valor que E, A^5+...+E^5 será menor que F^5. Por isso apresento uma versão dos loops aninhados otimizada. Confira-se:

```
//iniciar pelo F ao invés do A me pareceu mais legível
    //os trechos com continue e break servem para otimizar o algoritmo
    //as condições com continue verificam se é possível que no restante do loop R tenha o mesmo valor que F5
    //as condições com break verificam se R já não possuí um valor mais alto que F5
    for (int F = 1; F <= 75; F++) {     
        for (int E = 1; E <= F; E++) {
            if (P(F) > 5 * P(E)) continue;
            for (int D = 1; D <= E; D++) {
                if (P(F) > P(E) + 4 * P(D)) continue;
                if (P(F) < P(E) + P(D)) break;
                for (int C = 1; C <= D; C++) {
                    if (P(F) > P(E) + P(D) + 3* P(C)) continue;
                    if (P(F) < P(E) + P(D) + P(C)) break;
                    for (int B = 1; B <= C; B++) {
                        if (P(F) > P(E) + P(D) + P(C) + 2* P(B)) continue;
                        if (P(F) < P(E) + P(D) + P(C) + P(B)) break;
                        for (int A = 1; A <= B; A++) {  
                            int64_t F5 = P(F);
                            int64_t R = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) + P(D) + P(E);
                            if (F5 - R == 0) {
                                AC = A;
                                BC = B;
                                CC = C;
                                DC = D;
                                EC = E;
                                FC = F;
                                A = 81;// isso garante que todos os loops serão fechados
                                B = 80; // qunado  a resposta correta for encontrada
                                C = 79;
                                D = 78;
                                E = 77;
                                F = 76;
                            }
                            else if (F5 - R < 0) break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

E por fim, acrescento o algoritmo otimizado escrito de forma recursiva. Confira-se:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int64_t P(int x) {
    return x * x * x * x * x;
}

int compare(int* S, int index, int64_t f5, int64_t sum) {
    if (index == 1) return f5 == sum ? 0 : (f5 > sum ? 1 : -1);
    else return compare(S, index - 1, f5, sum + P(S[index - 1]));
}

int solve(int* S, int index) {
    if (index == 6)
        return (compare(S, index, P(S[0]), 0) == 0);

    if (index > 1) {
        if (compare(S, index, P(S[0]), 0) == -1) return 2;
        if (compare(S, index, P(S[0]), (6 - index) * P(S[index - 1])) == 1) return 3;
    }
    
    int max = index ? S[index - 1] : 75;

    for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
        S[index] = i;
        int s = solve(S, index + 1);
        if (s == 1) return 1;
        if (s == 2) break;
        if (s == 3) continue;
    }
    return  0;
}

int main(){
        
    int S[6] = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
    solve(S, 0);        
    printf("A=%d,B=%d,C=%d,D=%d,E=%d,F=%d\n",
            S[5], S[4],S[3],S[2],S[1], S[0]);   
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Acredito que faria muito mais sentido abstrair a lógica em uma função a parte e retornar os valores quando encontrado a solução do que atribuir valores *aleatórios* para forçar a parada dos laços.

Comment: Isso é engraçado, porque loops aninhados são um dos únicos casos em que goto ainda é indicado. Usar uma função também é possível ou uma flag, enfim. Eu cheguei a fazer com a função, mas decidi manter o código apresentado na resposta o mais parecido possível com o da pergunta para facilitar a leitura e a comparação.